# Select Box Blade

Tags: laravel

i try to remove the IDS from the select box who display the name , surname and licence number from a licence Object

here my controller :

```
 $licence_entraineur = Licencies::select('lb_nom', 'num_licence', 'lb_prenom', 'id')
            ->where(['structure_id' => Auth::user()->structure->id])
            ->where('type_licence_id' , '1')
            ->get()
            ->map(function($i) {
                return [$i->lb_nom.' - '.$i->lb_prenom.' - n°'.$i->num_licence];
            });
```

here my blade view :

```
 {!! Form::select('licence_entraineur_id', $licence_entraineur ,  null, ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'placeholder' => 'Selectionnez un Entraineur']) !!}
```

Everything works but when i go to my view and i make a dropdown of the select box , the values are display like this :

0
Mourareau - mathieu - 17085696

1
Antoine - George - 17209669

2
Aurore - Alonso - 17856965

i would like to remove the 0 , 1 , 2 , ... numbers to the view

someone know how to achieve that ? thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Please show the result of `dd($licence_entraineur)`

Comment: of course Collection {#823 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      9 => "Mourareau - Mathieu - n°17009538"
    ]
    1 => array:1 [▼
      10 => "dupont - jean - n°17890407"
    ]
    2 => array:1 [▼
      11 => "Mourareau - Mathieu - n°17928711"
    ]
    3 => array:1 [▼
      17 => "Mourareau - Mathieu - n°17915450"
    ]
    4 => array:1 [▼
      26 => "DamDam - Dodo - n°17568746"
    ]
    5 => array:1 [▼
      37 => "Aurore - Alonso - n°17921738"
    ]
  ]
}

Comment: I've added the answer. If you're using 5.4, this will work for you. BTW, I've added another solution to your last question yesterday, check it out. Also, do not remove `$i->id` part, because you'll need this key to be able to update data in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5.4 you can use `mapWithKeys()`. I've just tested and it works in 5.4 (in 5.3 this helper has a bug, so it's not working):

```
$licence_entraineur = Licencies::select('lb_nom', 'num_licence', 'lb_prenom', 'id')
        ->where(['structure_id' => Auth::user()->structure->id])
        ->where('type_licence_id' , '1')
        ->get()
        ->mapWithKeys(function($i) {
            return [$i->id => $i->lb_nom.' - '.$i->lb_prenom.' - n°'.$i->num_licence];
        });
```

Comment: AWESOME !!! glad to have L 5.4 !!!!!! thanks so much Alexey once again , i wish you a great day